# Where did Deoxys go?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

During the Delta missions, you run into Deoxys but don't have a chance to save beforehand. I accidentally fainted Deoxys and failed to catch him.

Soon afterwards I went to the Mossdeep Space Center where the scientists told me Deoxys had been tracked somewhere around route 131.

I searched route 131, and even sky pillar, but I couldn't find him. My question is, where is he now?

Comment: Oh, and my game version is **Alpha Sapphire**, if that makes any difference. Sorry, forgot to add that ;)

Answer (score 6):

You have the beat the Pokemon League again in order to meet Deoxys! You will find him at the top of sky pillar when you defeat the league for a second time!

Comment: @SkittyPaws - You can mark Aish's answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark under the vote count :) (This will award Aish with some extra rep points, and will show future visitors that the answer worked for you.

Comment: It's just not the same as battling in space :c

Answer (score 3):

When you beat the Pokemon League for the second time you will find him on top of Sky Pillar and you will have a second go at catching him.

Answer (score 0):

Beat the Pokemon leagues twice, go to top of sky pillar and save than catch him